# Hibernate Querying Tool other than Criteria

Tags: hibernate

Looking on the internet I have found out that for complex queries in Hibernate, where I need to fetch some object from the Database, I can use the Criteria API. As I understood, I cannot use it to somehow update or delete complex associations. Are there other other APIs which allow such functionality?

Comment: You mean other APIs within the hibernate to perform update/delete?

Comment: I mean any hibernate compatible APIs to perform all kind of crud operations

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for options to update/delete/insert (DML statements) using hibernate API. If so, you can have a look at the following options.

- Session API
   You can use methods directly on the Session object. Like `session.update/save/saveOrUpdate/delete...` apis. Refer [Hibernate-Userguide-Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e344)
- HQL
  You can use HQL queries to perform DML operations, using `session.createQuery(...)`. Refer [Hibernate-Userguide-HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e1739)
- Native SQL
  Another option is using `session.createSQLQuery(...)`, that allows to run the native SQL queries directly. Refer [Hibernate-Userguide-Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#querysql-cud)

One more option if the DML statements are in a stored procedure, you can call the stored procs using `session.createStoredProcedureCall(...)` api.